# Is it possible not to show app notification in drawer when location services are being used by an app in the background?

Tags: android, location, android-notifications, foreground-service

My app uses location services and I do not want it to show in the notification center. I was told that this is not possible in OS 9, when the foreground service is being used it must show in the drawer. However when I share my location in WhatsApp and have the app running in the background it does not show in the notification drawer. Is it possible to do this or not?

Comment: foreground services must show the icon, no way around it. The android notification that says "this app is using location" is also not under your control.

Comment: Not to mention on Android Q, it will now display a notification "Facebook got your location in the background". When clicking the notification it expands with the options "Deny, Allow, Allow Only While Using This App".

Comment: Its not possible to control, its for security purposes so the user knows that an app is accessing their location data. This was brought in as many apps retrieved location data without explaining it to the users and some users tend to just blindly accept the permissions without really knowing what the app wants